# Headers already sent in a simple php script

Tags: php, redirect

I'm having issues with my simple PHP script. I want if `$_SESSION['username']` is set to redirect to `welcome.php`, if not, it goes to `/login.php`
I thought it would be easy but i seem to have some issues.

**INDEX.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
  header("Location","/welcome.php");
}
else
{
  header("Location","/login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: you are calling header function in wrong way, try this `header("Location: /welcome.php");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `exit` after you redirect to page whenever you do it with condition. Also write header function as below

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
  header("Location: /welcome.php");
  exit();
}
else
{
  header("Location: /login.php");
  exit();
}
?>
```